# How use "html/template" for an inner object

Tags: go

Using a template to render data for HTML content, and "html/template" for an inner object in Go.

```
filedadta, err := template.ParseFiles("/home/rohith/Desktop/index.html")
tmpl := template.Must(filedadta, err)

var Allvalues []ReportFiled
        bodybuffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
        if err := tmpl.Execute(bodybuffer, Allvalues); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error in execute ")
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
```

Objects in side a file are like below , **but key value field inside unit struct is dynamic**

```
{
                    "id": 2,
                    "hostname": "172.31.33.44",
                    "username": "nothing",
                    "unit":{
                                "Application":"myapp",
                                "Location":"no" 
                    }
}

{
                    "id": ,
                    "hostame": "172.31.33.44",
                    "username": "nothing",
                    "unit":{
                                "Application":"myapp",
                                "Location":"no" ,
                                "name":"Unknown"
                    }
}
```

tried with this using below code

```
    <table class="tablecenter">  
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">Id</th>
          <th rowspan="2">UserName</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Hostname</th>
          <th colspan="3">unit</th>  // colspan="3" it will be N just for now given it as 3
       </tr>
    
    {{range .}}<tr>
    <td>{{unit.fields}}</td>
    </tr>
{{end}}
    </thead>
    
    {{range .}}<tr><td>{{.Hostname}}</td><td>{{.username}}</td>{{end}}
    
    {{range .}}
    <td>{{unit.value}}</td>
    </tr>{{end}}</table>
    
    </table>
```

**getting error in parsing file while executing it** if we **prase only for the parent element**
getting proper result.putting range with range {{range .}} throwing error.

```
type BHvaules struct {
        Field []string `json:"bhfield"`
        Value []string `json:"bhvalue"`
    }

    type ReportFiled struct {
        
        Username     string `json:"username"`
        BHvaules     BHvaules `json:"BHvaules"`
        Hostname     string   `json:"hostname"`
        ID       int      `json:"id"`
    }
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, we don't know what `Allvalues` is in Go source, and we don't know what `BHvalues` is in the templates. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: updated with minimal requirement

Comment: There must be an `{{end}}` closing tag for `{{range}}`. I don't see any in your template.